# What is the distribution of ${x}^T{x}$ for general multivariate Gaussian variable with nonzero mean?

Tags: statistics

I have been searching the web for some time and the result I get for the above distribution is for when ${x}{\sim}N(0,I)$ or $x{\sim}N(\mu,I)$ which is a central and non central $t$ distribution. I am interested to know the distribution of ${x}^T{x}$ for a general $x{\sim}N(\mu,\Sigma)$. Anyone knows what is it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For $x \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$ with covariance matrix $\Sigma$ arbitrary then I can show that $Y= x^{T}Ax$ follows a Chi-square distribution with $r$ degrees of freedom if and only if;

\begin{align}
A &=A \Sigma A \\
r &= rank(A)
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I am looking for a distribution without any constraint on $\Sigma$ or $A$.